# Не понимаю как вернуть значение на одной строчке

Tags: python, python-3.x, шифрование

Создаю шифр для шифрования пароля. Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно вернуть значение с помощью return на одной строчке, как это делается при использовании print (end=""). Не понимаю как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
def password_encryption(password):
    for password in password:
        password.capitalize()
        password.swapcase()
        cipher = ord(password) - len(password)
        if 0 < cipher < 129:
            cipher += (17 * 7)
        print(chr(cipher), end="")
password_encryption("123321")
```

выводит §¨©©¨§, а если писать return то каждый символ возвращается на отдельной строке.
Понимаю, что print только выводит текст на экран, а return возвращает значение функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def password_encryption(password):
    lst = ''
    for password in password:
        password.capitalize().swapcase()
        cipher = ord(password) - len(password)
        if 0 < cipher < 129:
            cipher += (17 * 7)
        #print(chr(cipher), end="")
        lst += chr(cipher)
    return lst

print(password_encryption("123321"))
```